# Mongoose - Need two schemas for full and min versions of a model for a document-collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

edited after @enRaiser's answer.

I have a sandbox mongoDB database with a single collection called "hotels", the document-schema of which looks like this:

```
var roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: String, 
  number: Number,
  description: String,
  photos: [ String ],
  price: Number
});

var hotelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    name: String, 
    stars: Number,
    description: String, 
    photos: [ String ],
    currency: String,

    location: {
        address: String,
        coordinates: [ Number ] /* enforce later validation to have max of two numbers in the array */
    },

    rooms: [roomSchema],

    reviews: [{
            name: String,
            id: String,
            review: String,
            rating: Number
    }],

    services: [ String ]
});
```

Now, I'd like to have two versions of schema for Hotel, one for a 'deep' data model and the other for a min model.

```
var hotelMinSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String, 
    stars: Number,
    location: {
        address: String,
        coordinates: [ Number ]
    },
    currency: String
})

module.exports = {
  full: mongoose.model('hotel', hotelSchema),
  min: mongoose.model('hotel', hotelMinSchema)
}
```

Aparently I'm not supposed to have two models for a collection.. not so sure. I get this error thrown.

> *OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `hotel` model once compiled.*

I think there should be a work-around for this. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: This still makes no sense. Why would you want to have two separate schemes for the same thing? Why don't you just use [optional attributes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required)?

Comment: Hotel.find({ }).select('name stars location currency').. gotcha.. 
Just found this. Please don't down vote..

Answer (score 0):

This is totally wrong way of developing any Database. even in MYSQL, I would not have think of this way of designing DB. 
Firstly there are  duplicate data.  You alwayse have to take care of syncing them.
and 2nd, even in your full  model there is duplication of comment. the comment info is present in both User ( i.e the commenter and the blogger)

Irrespective of the DB. when ever you think of  solution you have to  identify the real entities.  here in your use case there are only two entity User and comment. So just make two model. not more.(in case of MYSQL, I would say just make two tables   User table  and comment table.)

Then set up a relation between them.   for that in mongoose learn the how to make relation and how to populate that data based on relation.   its just like setting up foreign key in MYSQL.

Comment: I know @enRaiser. I know there's repetition. I don't have control over the existing data.. And repetition is not such a bad thing these days, (as storage is cheap)..

Comment: I edited my question. I know there's repetition of data, what I gave was a bad example to describe the issue I am facing. I now posted the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just found this out.

```
   var hotelListPromise = Hotel.find({})
            .select('name stars location currency')
            .exec((err, hotelData) => {
            // my callback stuff here
    });
```

Comment: So your strange approach was just to be able to do a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)? Why didn't you ask for that in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, it just didn't strike me until you commented. Thanks for that!

Comment: I feel so stupid now. I wish I can rewind this whole thing! aargh.. Sorry @str

Comment: On a separate note, @str, how can I also get the starting room price for each hotel in the same query?